# search and replace with in a file, with unknown amount of spaces

Tags: shell-script, sed

I am looking for small help on search and replace a string in a file.

my file content

```
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.1/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=    1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.2/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.3/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=   1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.4/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=  1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.1/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.2/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.3/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.5/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.6/16                     pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=1
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.7/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=      1
```

I tried with below command

```
sed -i "s/clientcert=*1/clientcert=verify-full/g" pg_hba.conf
```

it is worked for not expected result

```
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.1/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql **clientcert=    1**
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.2/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.3/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql **clientcert=   1**
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.4/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql **clientcert=  1**
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.1/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.2/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.20.3/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.5/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.6/16                     pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=verify-full
hostssl  all       all  192.168.10.7/16                    pam pamservice=postgresql clientcert=      1
```

kindly let me know the best alternative way to replace "clientcert=    1" with "clientcert=verify-full" by ignoring space between "="  and 1"

Comment: `sed -i 's/clientcert= *1/clientcert=verify-full/g' pg_hba.conf`

Comment: Look the space here -----------^

Comment: Hello Gilles Quenot, Thank you so much , your solution is worked as well

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer . below code worked for me

```
sed -i "s/clientcert=[[:space:]]*1/clientcert=verify-full/g" pg_hba.conf
```

Comment: Hello  Gilles Quénot, Let me try your solution. Thank you so much for quick response